# Check Whether Value is in part of value in Other Column Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to check if value from column "ket" is in "Ref" column. I use this code to do this

```
df['Check'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.ket in x.Ref, axis=1)
```

But it gets error like this:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

This is my sample data

| ket | Ref |
| --- | --- |
| 712 | 712,713 |
| 673 | 652 |
| 778 | 654,778 |

Expected result :

| ket | Ref | Check |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 712 | 712,713 | True |
| 673 | 652 | False |
| 778 | 654,778 | True |

Please help

Comment: I get "TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int" what are the dtypes of the columns?

Comment: You could try `df['Check'] = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.ket in x.Ref, axis=1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me. You can try this:

```
df['Check'] = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x['ket'] in x['Ref'], axis=1)
```